# ggplot2 geom with new default colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a series of charts that have `geom_bar`s with the same colour throughout. I prefer to be lazy and consequently, would like to avoid specifying`fill="blue"` each time.

How does one amend a default value for a geom or create a new version with an amended default, in line with the latest version of ggplot2? Is it as simple as the below?

```
geom_bluebar <- function(...) geom_bar(fill="blue", ...)
```

Comment: See also the vignette on [extending ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `?update_geom_defaults`.

```
update_geom_defaults("bar", list(fill = "blue"))
```